# Erro ao abrir conexão do MySQL via ADODB

Tags: mysql, visual-basic-6, ado

Estou tentando conectar um aplicativo feito em VB, Visual Studio 2017, usando como conexão o ADODB, porém está com vários erros para opções diferentes de conexão. Já me antecipando, eu conferi nos drivers das fontes de dados ODBC e consta lá o Driver 64 bits do MySQL("MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver" e "MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver")

TENTATIVA 1:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim aux As String
aux = "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver}; server=localhost,3306; Database=db-teste; uid=root; pwd=123456; Option=3;"
conn.Open(aux)
```

ERRO ENCONTRADO: Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado'

TENTATIVA 2:
Após criar uma nova fonte de dados ODBC de "Usuário" (guia "DSN de Usuário" das fontes de dados) com nome "Conexao_DB-TESTE" e outra fonte dados ODBC de Sistema (na guia "DSN de Sistema") com nome "Conexao_DB-TESTE2" e testar as duas como se segue, apresentou um erro diferente do anterior:

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open("Conexao_DB-TESTE")
```

ERRO: O DSN especificado contém uma incompatibilidade de arquiteturas entre o Driver e o Aplicativo

Não sei o que está errado e não encontrei outras opções. Como faço para estabelecer a conexão com MySQL via ADODB?

Answer (score 2):

Já resolvi. Baixei a versão anterior do driver do MySQL, Connector/ODBC 5.2.7, para 32 bits e recriei a DSN em "Fontes de de dados ODBC (32 bits)" nas Ferramentas Administrativas do Windows 10. [Link do driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/5.2.7.html)